# Ubuntu booting in mac

Tags: boot, usb, mac

I have installed Ubuntu on my USB drive according to the instructions here
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-real-ubuntu-os-usb-drive/

and the installation went successfully and Ubuntu was running on my mac.
After I restarted the mac I couldn't be able to boot Ubuntu again from the Startup Manager, When I press (Option ⌥) key I only found the main hard drive that boots me into macOS.

How can I solve this problem and boot into the USB drive again?

Comment: Do you know what the model/year of your Mac is?

Comment: @DavidAnderson MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Comment: I just wanted to confirm your Mac was not one of the legacy models that required BIOS booting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the sequence of steps needed to finish installing Ubuntu on a Mac. I assume you installed Ubuntu to use EFI booting.

1. Boot to Ubuntu live.
2. From the Desktop, press the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keys to open a Terminal window.
3. Enter the command shown below.

   ```
   sudo  fdisk  -l  /dev/sda
   ```

   Below is the output I saw from entering this command.

   > Note: For a better view, click on the image or open the image in a new window.

   [image: j0]
4. From the output of the `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` command, determine the device for the `EFI System` partition. For me, this was `/dev/sda1`. If you determine a different device, make the appropriate substitutions.
5. Enter the commands given below to make Ubuntu appear in the Startup Manager.

   ```
   sudo  bash
   mkdir  efi
   mount  /dev/sda1  efi
   cd  efi/EFI
   mkdir  BOOT
   cp  ubuntu/grubx64.efi  BOOT/bootx64.efi
   cd  ~
   umount  efi
   rmdir  efi
   exit
   exit
   ```
6. Shutdown Ubuntu live.
7. Startup the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear.
8. Click on the hard disk icon labeled "EFI Boot". Next, while holding down the <kbd>control</kbd> key, click on the circular arrow below this icon.

You are finished. Your Mac will now automatically boot to Ubuntu on startup and restart.