# Ubuntu on 2007 Macbook 2,1

Tags: boot, macbook, usb-installation

I have been having issues with other ways to update my mac, so I am looking for ways to install ubuntu on it. I have a 17.04 ubuntu disk, but I get the "Chose CD-Rom boot disk type" screen without it registering key presses.

And I have recently tried loading an amd64+mac 14.04 ISO to a USB, but the Mac found no way to boot to it in the options menu. (And I am not trying to dual-boot if that helps.). Any help will be appreciated.

### Mac Specifications:

- Intel Core 2 Duo
- 4 GB's of Ram
- 120 GB HDD (Blank from the issue with sfott)
- Model Name: Macbook 2,1

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 reached the end of its support life a while ago and is thus off topic here. Please try one of the supported Ubuntu releases from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Thanks.

Comment: Where could I find a mac iso for 17.10.1?

Comment: According to [the official tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1) the generic *Desktop* ISO will do. A link to the download page is included in the tutorial

Comment: This may sound like a stupid situation, but my mac doesnt have os x installed, so I have to make it from windows. would programs like rufus work to write the iso to the usb?

Comment: Good question! And one whose answer I don't know and if I did it would probably not fit into a comment. Thus, could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: I know this might be a really boring answer, but follow this article. (https://astrofloyd.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/boot-linux-from-usb-flash-drive-on-macbook/)

Comment: A mac that old may be incompatible with the os your trying to install. Did you try the following? 1. Delete the OS off the primary partition after booting into the recovery partition holding command + r and using disk utility. 2. Then plug in the USB. Power off the mac. 3. Press option and power. Does the USB installer show up?

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you broaden their scope which makes them harder to answer. On top of that it likely invalidates existing answers. I took the liberty to revert the edit that adds the follow-up question. Thanks.

Comment: You likely have a Macbook A1181. The same model as mine. Following links might help you in that case as it did helped me- (after a lot of trouble and failed attempts, I finally managed to install Ubuntu 16. Working excellent now ) https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/ https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ https://medium.com/@harijay/the-2007-plastic-macbook-lives-again-with-mint-y-linux-awesomeness-374469cc977e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Ubuntu from [this website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
2. Use [Etcher](https://etcher.io) to Transfer the downloaded ISO file to USB flash drive. You can use a computer running either macOS, Windows or Linux.
3. Insert flash drive into your Mac.
4. Start or restart you Mac. Immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the startup icons appear.
5. Select and flash drive icon with the label "EFI Boot". If two such icons appear, select either one.
6. Install Ubuntu.
7. Follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004129/ubuntu-booting-in-mac/1004966#1004966) after installing Ubuntu.

Your model Mac can not boot from a DVD which has the ability both BIOS and EFI boot. This is why your attempt to boot from the 17.04 Ubuntu disk failed. You Mac has 64 bit processors and a 64 bit EFI. The amd64+mac 14.04 ISO you downloaded is for Macs with 64 bit processors and a 32 bit EFI.

**Your model Mac can not to BIOS boot from a USB port. So if you download an ISO file that can both BIOS and 64 bit EFI boot, you need to transfer the ISO file to a USB flash drive. Burning to a DVD will not work.**

The table below shows the types of ISO files that can be used to install Linux on your model Mac. Also, included is the resulting type of booting that will occur if Linux is installing using either a flash drive or DVD.

```
             Boot types in ISO File                       Installed OS Boot Type
----------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
32 Bit EFI   64 bit EFI   32 bit BIOS   64 bit BIOS   Transfer to USB    Burn to DVD
----------   ----------   -----------   -----------   ---------------    -----------
                                            X                            64 Bit BIOS
                              X                                          32 Bit BIOS
                  X                                     64 Bit EFI       64 Bit EFI
                  X                         X           64 Bit EFI
                  X           X                         32 Bit EFI
     X                                                  32 Bit EFI       32 Bit EFI
     X                        X                         32 Bit EFI
     X            X                                     32 Bit EFI
     X            X           X                         32 Bit EFI
```